# ASP.NET MVC domain Models and Identity Models in same context - UserLogin has no key

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I want my application models to be in the same DBContext that has the identity model. So I inserted my classes into the IdentityDbContext like this:

```
public partial class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext() : base("HumanTask")
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<wfInstance> wfInstance { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<wfService> wfService { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<wfTask> wfTask { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<wfWorkflow> wfWorkflow { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<wfTask>()
                .Property(e => e.wfTaskId)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<wfWorkflow>()
                .Property(e => e.Name)
                .IsUnicode(false);
        }
    }
```

}

now, when I try to create a new controller for one of my classes classes using the scaffold

[image]

I get a message like this:

[image]

I think I'm missing something on my OnModelCreating function, but I cant tell what. Help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error looks like you are missing key attributes for your IdentityUserLogin and IdentityUser role models. You will need to specify a key on your model like this:

```
public partial class IdentityUserLogin
{
    [Key]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Or you can specify it with a fluent API

```
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>() 
    .HasKey(t => t.UserName);
```